# Kitchen sink has a messy layout Framework7

Tags: html-framework-7

I am starting to use Framework7 and I have successfully ran the kitchen sink on localhost:3000. However, it gives me something like this
[image]

can anybody please tell me why? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the index.html file from dist folder. Not from kitchen sink. Kitchen sink is to get the extra (utilities) features for the app.

Answer (score 0):

Framework7 uses `gulp` to build a development (build) and dist versions.

First you need to have `gulp-cli` which you should install globally.

`$ npm install --global gulp`

Then install all dependencies, in repo's root:

`$ npm install`

And build development version of Framework7:

`$ gulp build`

The result is available in `build/` folder.

### Dist/Release

After you have made build:

`$ gulp dist`

Distributable version will available in `dist/` folder.

### Custom build

You can build custom version of Framework7 with only required components/modules. For example, if we need to include only Accordion, Modals and Tabs modules in addition to Framework 7 core:

`$ gulp custom -accordion,modals,tabs`

After that you will find created `custom/` folder with generated JS and CSS files. Here is the list of available additional modules: